# How to list opened dataReadres

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I'm receiving an "*A DataReader associated with this Command is already open. It must first be closed*" error (translated from French, might not be accurate). I understand the problem but have not a trivial way to know which the “already open DataReader” is. My question is: When I stop on the error, do I have a way to list or see the currently opened dataReders.
Thanks in advance.
BB

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using the same connection. Try to enclose your code in a `using` statement as showed below

```
using (SqlConnection conn  = new SqlConnection())
{
    conn.Open();
    Sqlmd.Connection = conn;  // Sqlmd is your command
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Sqlmd);
   //...etc
}
```

Comment: I’m using EF4.1 CodeFirst and LinqToEntities, consequently I do not manually manage connections and adapters. I do not see how to enclose my LinqToEntities queries in a using block. Thanks anyway